# Align text to the bottom of a div

Tags: css, html, text, vertical-alignment

I tried to align my text to the bottom of a div from other posts and answers in Stack Overflow I learned to handle this with different CSS properties. But I can't get it done. Basically my HTML code is like this:

```html
<div style='height:200px; float:left; border:1px solid #ff0000; position:relative;'>
  <span style='position:absolute; bottom:0px;'>A Text</span>
</div>
```

The effect is that in FF I just get vertical line (the div in a collapsed way) and the text is written next to it. How can I prevent the `div` collapsing but having the width fitting to the text?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

#### Flex Solution

It is perfectly fine if you want to go with the `display: table-cell` solution. But instead of hacking it out, we have a better way to accomplish the same using `display: flex;`. `flex` is something which has a [decent support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.wrap span {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span>Align me to the bottom</span>
</div>
```

In the above example, we first set the parent element to `display: flex;` and later, we use [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) to `flex-end`. This helps you push the item to the end of the `flex` parent.

---

#### Old Solution (Valid if you are not willing to use `flex`)

If you want to align the text to the bottom, you don't have to write so many properties for that, using `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: bottom;` is enough

```css
div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

[(Or JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/)

Comment: Cool!!! That's it! It works also without the width-property which I have to omit for haveing the div fitting to the content. Thanks!

Comment: @parascus It saves you so many properties which you were trying with.. and you welcome :)

Comment: @blackhawk why would you use this solution if your parent wrapper is set to `inline-block`? This is specifically for people who can use `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 58):

You now can do this with Flexbox `justify-content: flex-end` now:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Something to align
</div>
```

[Consult your Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) to see if Flexbox is right for you.

Comment: Do you know of a way to align to the bottom *left* using this method?

Comment: @PrestonBadeer just use `justify-content: flex-start;` or remove it altogether.

Comment: how to center the text here ?

Comment: @kkkk00999 Try with `justify-content: center`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you have already answered a flex solution. I've added a similar one because my solution was old. Someone commented and I thought that it's time to update. Hope you don't mind.