# max-width of img inside flexbox doesn't preserve aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to use `flex` to simply vertically center an `img` inside `div`, but it is working differently in each browser.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 222px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.flex-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.item-image {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8264/8700922582_d7b50280b4_z.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0m2d6hx/

It is good in chrome, but in IE and FF it looks like it doesn't work with `max-width`.

Can anyone help me with this? I know that I can center the `img` without `flex` but I want to understand this.

Comment: Interesting problem. FF seems to think that whatever is inside a flex box, should itself be flexible as well. Even if you remove the align-self property, the larger image still behaves that way. Not sure about a workaround.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### How to fix IE and Firefox

The following changes should result in the same result across Chrome, Firefox and IE:

- Add `flex: 0 0 auto;` to `.flex-item img`. This fixes IE
- Add `object-fit: scale-down;` to `.flex-item img`. This fixes Firefox

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex-item {
  height: 222px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.flex-item img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
.item-image {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 190px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://www.joshuacasper.com/contents/uploads/joshua-casper-samples-free.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8264/8700922582_d7b50280b4_z.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/ilovesamples.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://appslova.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Android-.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7yyf3nob/

### Why does this happen?

Unfortunately I can't explain why the result between the browsers is so different other than it would appear that the natural resizing properties of an `img` are lost when using the `flexbox` model in IE and Firefox. `flexbox` is still a relatively new model and the vendors are still refining their implementations.

Answer (score 0):

[Images in flex items are not resized correctly with max-width:PERCENTAGE](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1109992)

Modified version of the W3C CSS Flexbox example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   W3C FLEX EXAMPLE MODIFIED TO ADD FLEX TOOLBAR
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
  </title>
  <style>
   body{
    font-size: 3vh;
   }
   .flexToolbar {
     background-color: DodgerBlue;
     display: flex;
     flex-basis: 64%;
     flex-wrap: nowrap;
     font-size: 1.5vh;
     font-weight: bolder;
   }
   .flexToolbar > div {
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123327/align-text-to-the-bottom-of-a-div */
    align-self: flex-end;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    /* Your flex items are set to "min-width: auto", which gives them a min-width equal to their intrinsic width. 
       If you style your .container divs with "min-width: 0" you get the behavior I think you expect. 
       https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1109992
    */
    min-width: 0;
    text-align: center;
   }
   .flexToolbarImage {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 64%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>
  <div class="flexToolbar">
   <div>
    <img id="dbImport" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.import.png" alt="IMPORT DB" />
    IMPORT
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbNew" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.new.png" alt="NEW DB" />
    NEW
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbCreate" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.create.png" alt="CREATE TABLE" />
    CREATE
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbDrop" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.drop.png" alt="DROP TABLE" />
    DROP
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbInsert" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.insert.png" alt="INSERT ROWs" />
    INSERT
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbUpdate" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.update.png" alt="UPDATE ROWs" />
    UPDATE
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbDelete" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.delete.png" alt="DELETE ROWs" />
    DELETE
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbSelect" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.select.png" alt="SELECT ROWs" />
    SELECT
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbSQL" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.sql.png" alt="WRITE SQL"/>
    SQL
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbExport" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.export.png" alt="EXPORT DB" />
    EXPORT
   </div>
   <div>
    <img class="flexToolbarImage" src="vertical.line.png" alt="|" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <img id="dbRun" class="flexToolbarImage" src="db.run.png" alt="RUN SQL" />
    RUN
   </div>
  </div>
  <p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
  <p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```